# JS обновление рандома в викторине при нажатии правильного ответа

Tags: javascript

Задача: сделать так, чтобы после нажатия на правильный ответ выводилось новое выражение и новые ответы на кнопках, счёт обновлялся. Я думаю, что это действие можно реализовать с помощью метода onclick, но не знаю, как.

```js
var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var numbers = generateRandomNumbers(squares.length - 1);

let numberDisplayFirst = document.querySelector("#numberdisplayfirst");
let numberDisplaySecond = document.querySelector("#numberdisplaysecond");
let amountDisplay = document.getElementById("amountDisplay");
var accountGame = document.querySelector("#account");
var Score = 0;

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

let firstNumber = getRandomInt(1, 10);
let secondNumber = getRandomInt(1, 10);
var sumNumbers = firstNumber * secondNumber;

numberDisplayFirst.textContent = firstNumber;
numberDisplaySecond.textContent = secondNumber;

numbers.push(sumNumbers);
numbers.sort(function(){ return Math.random() - 0.5 });


for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    squares[i].textContent = numbers[i]
    squares[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        var clickedNumber = this.textContent;
        if(clickedNumber == sumNumbers){
            Score++;
            accountGame.textContent = Score;
        } else {
            alert("wrong");//игра заканчивается
        }
    })
}

function generateRandomNumbers(num) {
    var arr=[]
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++){
    arr.push(randomNumbers());    
    }
    return arr;
}

function randomNumbers(){
    var first = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
    return "" + first;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Игра на знание таблицы уравнений</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><span id="numberdisplayfirst"></span> x <span id="numberdisplaysecond"></span></h1>
        <div id="container">
            <button class="square"></button>    
            <button class="square"></button>
            <button class="square"></button>
        </div>
        <div>Счёт: <span id="account">0</span></div>
        <script src="index.js"></script>    
    </body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас же и так уже есть функция, создающая случайное число. Можно было не создавать дополнительные на создание случайного массива.

```js
let accountGame = document.getElementById("account");
let answer;
let score = 0;

startGame();

document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if ( !e.target.className.match(/square/) ){ return; }

  if ( e.target.textContent == answer ) {//Если число внутри кликнутой совпадает с ответом
    startGame(); // Запускается новый вопрос.
  } else {
    alert('Ошибка!');
    score = 0;
    startGame();
  }
});

function startGame() {
  let first = getRandomInt(1, 10);
  let second = getRandomInt(1, 10);
  document.getElementById("first").textContent = first;
  document.getElementById("second").textContent = second;
  // Нет разницы как назвать тут переменные. 
  // Всё равно используются только тут. Создали - записали - забыли.

  answer = first * second;
  let squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
  let length = squares.length;

  let numbers = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
    let x = getRandomInt(1, 100);
    while (~numbers.indexOf(x) || x === answer) { // Проверка, чтобы не было повторных ответов
      x = getRandomInt(0, 100);
    }
    numbers.push(x);
  }
  numbers.push(answer);
  numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (Math.random() - 0.5);// sort тут не работает без скобок, как оказалось.
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    squares[i].textContent = numbers[i];
  }

  document.getElementById('account').textContent = score++;
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

```css
.square {
  font-size: 25px;
  min-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<h1><span id="first"></span> x <span id="second"></span></h1>
<div id="container">
  <button class="square"></button>
  <button class="square"></button>
  <button class="square"></button>
</div>
<div>Счёт: <span id="account">0</span></div>
```

P.s. У вас то let, то var... конкретно тут - нет разницы.

P.s-2 в куске с созданием массива, можно было сразу вставить число в случайноe место и не пересортировать всё лишний раз:

```
let numbers = [];
let correct = Math.floor( Math.random() * length );
for (let i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
  if( i = correct ) { numbers.push( correct ); continue; }
  let x = getRandomInt(0, 100);
  while (~numbers.indexOf(x) || x === answer) { // Проверка, чтобы не было повторных ответов
    x = getRandomInt(0, 100);
  }
  numbers.push(x);
}
```

Или вообще не создавать никакой массив и прямо в цикле и вставить:

```
let correct = Math.floor( Math.random() * length );
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  squares[i].textContent = ( i !== correct ) ? numbers[i] : correct;
}
```

Comment: Ну вот, всё пришлось переписывать :с Я всё поняла кроме единственной строчки: if (!e.target.className.match(/square/)){return}; - что она обозначает?

Comment: @Анна Чередниченко Хотя можно было добавить клик и на все кнопки.square по отдельности, но таракан в голове подсказал добавить одно событие на общий блок, а при клике - проверять, на что именно кликнули (оно срабатывает и при клике на пробелы между кнопками и т.п.). Вот и проверяется - если при клике, у кликнутого элемента `e.target` не оказалось класса square, ключевое слово `return` прерывает выполнение функции, чтобы дальше не было ошибки. P.s. `!` перед условием означает 'НЕ'. Т.е. если match найдет "square" среди классов и вернет true, `!` превратит его в false и условие не выполнится.

Comment: @Анна Чередниченко можно поизвращаться и организовать умножение очков на потраченное время на ответ)) Вначале функции создавая `new Date();` и сравнивая его с предыдущим созданным. Т.е. чтобы на каждом круге прибавлялась не единица, а `4 / время * время` , например — до 2 секунды на ответ для нормы. Или таймер: не успел ответить, проиграл... который будет становится быстрее с каждым ответом ( setTimeout, привязанный к количеству ответов )